# What ways are there for classes to provide progress information

Tags: c#

I have multiple classes that do lengthy tasks in threads and want them to output some kind of progress, so i can display it to a progress bar or a counter.

I could use an event or a delegate, defined in an interface, but it seems for every implementation I will need to write the exact same FireEvent code to check if the event is null and raise it, if it's not.

Using an abstract class seems bad too, since functionality like that does not belong in the top most class, which means I have to implement it at different places again.

How do I do that in the most reusable way, without duplicate code everywhere?

Comment: Why does functionality like that not belong in a base class?  The whole point of a base class is to provide shared functionality between derived classes

Comment: why would all classes report progress the same way?

Comment: @vidstige Maybe you assign it a progress bar to update and it updates that progress bars. All classes will update the assigned progress bar. They all report progress in the same way in this example.

Comment: I hope you have multiple _objects_ that do lengthy words. If you have classes the work is in static methods and you can forget about inheritance

Comment: Ben: you are right, but many classes have base classes that are out of my control(3rd party framework). I know there are patterns around this, but that means for every occurrence I have to implement it again. That seems wasteful for such basic functionality.

Comment: @Darcara Why can't you lay your own base on top of the 3rd party base, implement your widespread functionality, and then have all your workers inherit your base?

Comment: izuriel: I could, but I'd have to do that multiple times, as not all classes that need this functionality have the same base class. I just wondered if there is a simpler/cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a `BackgroundWorker` for your other threads, you can use the `ReportProgress` method, which will raise the `ProgressChanged` event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Nice!  I love learning new stuff like this.  New to me, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I usually *reverse* the relationship between the view and the model so that the view knows about the model. In this example the progress dialog would have a reference to a `IProgress` interface. It then hooks up to a `ProgressChanged` event and the view can thus update itself when it needs to. The main advantage of this is the code inside the various classes are not duplicated - Only the code that tells how much is left is inside those classes. This way it is also very easy to clamp progress updates of classes that emit progress status very often.

Just to give you an idea what I usually do:

```
interface IProgress
{
    event EventHandler ProgressChanged;
    int ProgressTarget { get; }
    int CurrentProgress { get; }
}
```

And a implementing class. I don't even know if it works as it should - It's just to give an impression on how to implement this interface.

```
class StreamCopier: IProgress
{
    private Stream _source;
    private Stream _destination;

    public StreamCopier(Stream source, Stream destination)
    {
        _source = source;
        _destination = destination;
    }

    public void WriteAll()
    {
        int b;
        while ((b = _source.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            _destination.WriteByte((byte)b);
            EventRaiser.Raise(ProgressChanged, this); // Just one call here! Can't be less
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler ProgressChanged;

    public int ProgressTarget {
        get { return (int)_source.Length; }
    }

    public int CurrentProgress {
        get { return (int)_destination.Position; }
    }
}
```

And then the `EventRaiser` class. Note how the handler reference is passed on the parameter stack, and therefor no thread-safe copy to a 'tmp' is necessary! :)

```
static class EventRaiser
{
    public static void Raise(EventHandler handler, object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        handler(sender, args);
    }

    public static void Raise(EventHandler handler, object sender)
    {
        Raise(handler, sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is what I'm trying to avoid actually. Every time the Progress changed event is fired, it has to be checked for null. It's usually in a RaiseEvent function, but this has to be implemented every time. I know it's not much, but I'd rather hav a fire and forget RaiseProgressChanged method available, that I do not need to implement every time I need it somewhere.

Comment: Alright, yeah I hate this too. It's more of a problem with the language. See my edit to see how I cope with this.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't answer the question but it is very interesting nevertheless.  +1 for the extra effort explaining it.